# Load Testing the UI recommendations for a quasar project

Tags: jmeter, robotframework, performance-testing, ui-testing, locust

#### Current State

We have an SPA application developed with quasar. We have been successfully able to load test the APIs via locust and also run automation tests via Robot Framework.

#### Objective

Since the APIs were only load tested via locust, we wanted to load test the behavior of our system, when there will be multiple users accessing our UI giving us answers to questions like

1. How many users will be able to access the UI without slowing it down.
2. Monitoring the response times as the number of user increase.

#### Clarifications Needed

As a starter in performance testing, I wanted recommendations on which tool would be the best to load test the UI.

1. Is it possible to hook the automation tests of Robot Framework to locust?
2. Can we just include the selenium library in python and execute those automation scripts in locust to load test the UI?
3. Should we be using tools like JMeter or any other tools which can achieve our requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is possible, see [Extending Locust using event hooks](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html)
2. Yes, there is even an example [locustfile](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/webdriver.py) you can use as the reference
3. JMeter per se doesn't have any frontend performance testing capabilities so you will need to follow the same approach by integrating JMeter with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/)

You may find [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Robot/) tool useful, it is capable of executing [Robot Framework](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Robot/) tests and [Locust](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Locust/) tests so you can kick off them both at the same moment by supplying the configuration via simple [YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) file and have the results at the same place

Comment: Thanks for the response Dmitri. Can you please elaborate a bit further on your first point. I checked the link you mentioned but I am finding it a bit confusing on exactly how and where to add the code to run the robotframework file. 

e.g, I have a robotTest.robot file which I normally run from the terminal via below command
`robot robotTest.robot`
How exactly will I run the robotTest.robotfile via locust. The events like request_success etc. are available but I am not able to get it from the documentation on how to executed a robot file using those events.